# Defining my own command

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to define my own command in MacVim to turn a c statement or range of statements into comments.  So I put this in my vimrc:

```
command -range Com :<line1>,<line2>s?^.*$?/*&*/?
```

It works fine if I just enter :Com to comment the current line.  But if I enter something like :Com 3 5 in order to turn lines 3 thru 5 into comments I always get this error message:

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you were looking for functionality to comment single/multiple lines easily, look no further than the [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide the range *before* the command, like that:

```
:3,5Com
```

Anyway, I suggest you to check the [NERD_commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) plugin. It's great for commenting source code.

Comment: That's it!  Thx, Adam.  I'm checking NERD_commenter.